# How make a beautiful animated cells?

Tags: modeling, animation

i make actually a skin cell simulation, like this video reference : [www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYNgLQNpA6E](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYNgLQNpA6E)

and I have no more solution for make cells like this ref :

[image: Cells ref]

So, I tried making an object with Array modifier and Curve modifier, but it's very limited :

[image: Modifier array+curve]

I tried with soft body simulation, the best considering that i intend to make animations where cells are repelled by emerging news :

[image: Cells soft body]

Except that it works for a few cells but when there are many it is impossible to manage, even with a good computer.

I was wondering how they did it in this film, what methods to use ?

If someone would have other solutions I am interested ! :)

Cordially,

Comment: Research about the "tissue" addon.

Comment: You have added the "animation" tag. Can you please add a description of how the cells are moving or add an example gif? Not everyone will want to watch the whole youtube link. I would also suggest removing the softbody tag, since it is about a solution, but not the problem.

Comment: For animation i said " that i intend to make animations where cells are repelled by emerging news" in the movie ref you can saw this at 0:58, but I want to make more regrown cells, that's why i try this with soft body. Thx i look about tissue addon, I already tried with BY-GEN.

Comment: Hmm, if BY-GEN didn't work, I don't think Tissue will help.

Comment: With By-GEN i make the bottom part of cells, it's very effective ! But for cells maybe it's because i don't know the addon yet..